# BluetoothDevice not found in android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In android studio i am getting

> Incompatible types. Found: 'android.os.Parcelable[]', required:
>   'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice

error in this line 
"`BluetoothDevice device=intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);`"
please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: How do I ask a good question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you saw question like yours with info you provided would you know how to help? Provide logCat and code which gives you error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `getParcelableArrayExtra` with `getParcelableExtra` since BluetoothDevice implements Parcelable.

Comment: You're welcome ! Could you please accept my answer ?